# How to force Opera play mp3s with jPlayer?

Tags: jquery, html, mp3, jplayer, ogg

How to force Opera play mp3s?

I use jPlayer,  In mozilla - all good, play mp3, but Opera dont wont :(
If I use ogg, Opera play, but mp3... :(
oggSupport: Boolean : (Default: false) : Enables ogg support in HTML5 with OGG format browsers. But if I put "false" still does not help...

example: http://global-news.com.ua/page_113.html?unitId=11501 Right in the middle of the page

```
var fff  =     [{
            title:"Sleep Away",
            mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Sleep_Away.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            title:"Maid with the Flaxen Hair",
            mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Maid_Hair.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            title:"Kalimba",
            mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Kalimba.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        }];

    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, fff, {
        swfPath: "../i.files/JS",
        supplied: "mp3, oga",
        wmode: "window",
        oggSupport: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    });
```

Try:

```
var fff  =     [{
            title:"Sleep Away",
            mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Sleep_Away.mp3"
        },
        {
            title:"Maid with the Flaxen Hair",
            mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Maid_Hair.mp3"
        },
        {
            title:"Kalimba",
            mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Kalimba.mp3"
        }];

    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, fff, {
        swfPath: "../i.files/JS",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        oggSupport: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    });
```

but does not help :(

Answer (score 1):

Opera doesn't support Mp3 format on tag Audio. 
JPlayer provides "Flash Fallback" functionality for non-native formats.
For enable it you must:

- Check the SWF path
- Add `solution:"flash,html"` into your code in this way:

  ```
  var fff   =   [{
      title:"Sleep Away",
      mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Sleep_Away.mp3"
  },
  {
      title:"Maid with the Flaxen Hair",
      mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Maid_Hair.mp3"
  },
  {
      title:"Kalimba",
      mp3:"http://www.global-news.com.ua/audio/Kalimba.mp3"
  }];

  new jPlayerPlaylist({
      jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
      cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
  }, fff, {
      swfPath: "../i.files/JS",
      solution:"flash,html"
      supplied: "mp3",
      wmode: "window",
      oggSupport: false,
      smoothPlayBar: true,
      keyEnabled: true
  ```

  });

Try it!